# Crash on _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex when calling CGPathRelease on CGPath object

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, core-text

I'm getting a crash that I am completely stumped on, when releasing a CGPath object. The crash is occurring in the [CoreTextHyperlinkView](https://github.com/jasarien/CoreTextHyperlinkView) library at the end of the `- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx bounds:(CGRect)bounds` method in the `JSCoreTextView` class.

Basically it's using Core Graphics/Text to draw underlined text. It creates a path, draws it, then releases it.

Here is the relevant stack trace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x319058b6 _CFArrayGetValueAtIndex + 2
1   MyApp                               0x00300891 -[JSCoreTextView drawInContext:bounds:] (JSCoreTextView.m:678)
2   MyApp                               0x00300c5f -[JSCoreTextView drawRect:] (JSCoreTextView.m:709)
3   UIKit                               0x337ded61 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 365
4   QuartzCore                          0x3358f315 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 113
5   QuartzCore                          0x3358e8c3 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1779
6   QuartzCore                          0x3358e037 CA::Layer::display_() + 975
7   QuartzCore                          0x335850b7 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 203
8   QuartzCore                          0x33584fe1 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 25
9   QuartzCore                          0x335849c3 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 239
10  QuartzCore                          0x335847d5 CA::Transaction::commit() + 317
11  QuartzCore                          0x33584639 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 61
12  CoreFoundation                      0x3199b941 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
13  CoreFoundation                      0x31999c39 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 277
14  CoreFoundation                      0x31999f93 __CFRunLoopRun + 747
15  CoreFoundation                      0x3190d23d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
16  CoreFoundation                      0x3190d0c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
17  GraphicsServices                    0x354ec33b _GSEventRunModal + 75
18  UIKit                               0x338292b9 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
19  MyApp                               0x0003fad7 main (main.m:13)
```

It seems like some array internal the the CGPath is causing the problem. Could this just be a Core Text or Core Graphics bug in iOS? I'm stuck as to how to go about investigating further as I can't look into the source code of the iOS SDK.

We only use this view in a modified [BlockAlertView](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets) like this below example. We're getting the text from our JSON API in either english or arabic, which may contain email addresses or URLs to be underlineed and linkified.

```
JSCoreTextView *coreTextView = [[JSCoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kAlertViewBorder, _height, frame.size.width-kAlertViewBorder*2, size.height)];
coreTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
coreTextView.delegate = self;
coreTextView.text = message;
coreTextView.textColor = _messageColor;
coreTextView.textAlignment = kCTCenterTextAlignment;
coreTextView.fontName = _messageFont.fontName;
coreTextView.fontSize = _messageFont.pointSize;
coreTextView.linkColor = _messageColor;
coreTextView.highlightedLinkColor = _messageLinkColor;
coreTextView.highlightColor = _messageColor;
coreTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
coreTextView.underlined = YES;           
[_view addSubview:coreTextView];
```

Comment: I think you should look in the implementation of `drawInContext:bounds:` for unbound array accesses. `CGPathRelease` doesn't seem to be the trigger.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: If you look at [the current version of the source code](https://github.com/jasarien/CoreTextHyperlinkView/blob/3184fd228d/Classes/JSCoreTextView.m), line 678 (the line identified in the stack trace) is, indeed, a call to `CGPathRelease`. That being said, though, I can't see a way that that release could be unbalanced (unless Core Text itself is doing something highly dodgy). Instruments's Zombies template would prove it one way or the other.

Comment: I can see any reason why that should be crashing... Could you show some code where you use the hyperlink view, so we can get an idea of context?

Comment: Wow talk about timing, looks like this may be happening because of this bug: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/08/rendering-bug-crashes-os-x-and-ios-apps-with-string-of-arabic-characters/ as our app is English and Arabic localized.

Comment: I'm investigating that possibility today.

Comment: Looks like it's not that bug, as we're seeing a similar crash on iOS 7 as well. I'll add an example of use to the question